# AngularJS Usage of Local/Global scope variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below is my HTML code along with JS script. I need to Change the value of "label" after the button click but it is not changing and using global values only.

http://plnkr.co/edit/T4EaZglOnq8Q2UVLWNFm?p=preview

My preview/Plnkr can be seen here..

JS CODE:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);


app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.firstName = "John";

    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
    $scope.year1=1992;
    $scope.year2=1994;
    $scope.year3=1996;
    $scope.label=[$scope.year1,$scope.year2,$scope.year3];
  $scope.splitYears = function()
  {      

      $scope.year1=2202;
      $scope.year3=2004;
      $scope.year2=2001;     

      $scope.checking=[$scope.year1,$scope.year2,$scope.year3];      
  }
   $scope.checking1=[$scope.year1,$scope.year2,$scope.year3];  
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are never updating your `$scope.label` property inside of the click handler.

```
$scope.splitYears = {
    $scope.year1=2202;
    $scope.year3=2004;
    $scope.year2=2001;
    $scope.label=[$scope.year1,$scope.year2,$scope.year3];
    $scope.checking=[$scope.year1,$scope.year2,$scope.year3];    
}
```

You are also binding label to an array of objects, not an object directly.

As a result, there's no referenced value that is updated when you update your objects (since they're masked by the array) and AngularJS doesn't realize that it needs to update label.

If instead you bound `$scope.label` directly to `$scope.year1`, you would see label properly update on the UI.

Another option is to use a $watch/$watchCollection and automatically update your label outside of the click handler if your year changes.

```
$scope.array = [$scope.year1,$scope.year2,$scope.year3]
$scope.label = $scope.array;

$scope.$watchCollection("year1", function (newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.label = [$scope.year1, $scope.year2, $scope.year3];
});

$scope.splitYears = function() {      
    $scope.year1=2202;
    $scope.year3=2004;
    $scope.year2=2001;
    $scope.checking=[$scope.year1,$scope.year2,$scope.year3];
}
```

Comment: I m updating $scope.year1, $scope.year2, $scope.year3  inside the click event..

I want my output as
Outside :[1992,1994,1996]

Inside :[2202,2001,2004]

[2202,2001,2004]

Comment: So I need to create years object and assign to label ?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  Your comment above changed my understanding of your question.

Comment: Once Check the plunk..
I need to assign the $scope.year1 that been changed inside the button click handler  to a new $scope.variable(Outside the click handler) and show it on UI.

Comment: @offeron I've added an additional option that won't interfere with your click logic.